# React production router 404 after deep refresh firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-hosting

i have this routes in my index.js

```
 <Router history={customHistory}>
        <div className="row">
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/login" component={Login}/>
                <Route path="/home" component={Home}/>
                <Route path="/politicas" component={Policies}/>

                <Redirect exact from="/" to="/login"/>
                <Route exact path="*" status={404} component={NotFound}/>

            </Switch>

        </div>
    </Router>
```

In local enviroment always works but i have one firebase application, to deploy my firebase project i use:

> npm run build

and

> firebase deploy

But in firebase app after deep refresh returns 404, the only route that works is "/", What do I have to do to keep the routes always working with any path?

Comment: Thanks so much!! I thought it was a react problem, I was looking for days.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

I answer myself, it is necessary to add the following to the file firebase.json

```
"hosting": {
  // Add the "rewrites" section within "hosting"
  "rewrites": [ {
    "source": "**",
    "destination": "/index.html"
  } ]
}
```

Comment: Why is the reason because react router doesn't works?

Comment: Firebase has his own server and when you navigate to **/something** the server thinks there is a directory or file in that path so, when you rewrite the file firebase.json like i put in the example all your traffic is going to the index.html file and react router take all these traffic instead.

Comment: this still returns a status code of 200 rather 404 as it should. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: Hey thanks for coming back and posting this solution. I was pulling my hair out. Your answer fixed everything.

Comment: Hey the problem in my case seems to be, that every time I try npm run build and firebase init again - to host it again - firebase.json resets.

Comment: Great answer thank you so much! I was getting 404 on manual refresh only of my React/Firebase app and this fixed it in a jiffy. Great post!!